# Cant find the error in the PHP code (The site is on Norwegian, but just read the code)

Tags: php

a maked a "index.php" file with a HTML form who was like this:

```
<form action="send.php" method="get">
```

The form have many textfields and a submit button who works fine, but the error is in the document called "send.php". Please help me finding the bugs! Here is the code: (Below)

```
<?php
                $fileread = fopen('data.txt', 'r');
                $filewrite = fopen('data.txt', 'w');
                $age = $_GET['age'];
                $use = $_GET['use'];
                $sites = $_GET['sites'];
                $connection = $_GET['connection'];
                $service = $_GET['service'];
                $other = $_GET['other'];
                $text = 'Alder: "' . $age . '" Bruk: "' . $use . '" Brukes mest på sider i sjangere, som: "' . $sites . '" Tillkobling: "' . $connection . '" Brukerservice: "' . $service . '" Andre kommentarer fra brukeren: "' . $other . '"';
                $data = fgets($fileread);
                fwrite($data, $filewrite);
                                    fwrite($text, $filewrite);
                echo 'Sendt!';
            ?>
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of opening the file two times one for reading and one for writing: just open one time with

```
$filehandle = fopen('data.txt', 'r+');
```

If you want to append the new data at the end of the file just do that (you don't need to read the file and rewrite)

Go to the end of the file

```
fseek ( $filehandle , 0 ,SEEK_END );
```

and write

```
fwrite($filehandle, $text);
```

Note that first parameter of fwrite is the file handle, not the data. This is the error.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have your [fwrite](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) parameters inverted. It should be fwrite($handle, $string);

You should try

```
fwrite($filewrite,$data);
fwrite($filewrite,$text);
```